# KendoUI Grid Stays in Edit-Mode after Update

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Server Wrappers for the KendoUI Grid using AJAX for binding (v2013.1.319) and am utilizing inline editing.  When I edit a record and click update, the post occurs on the server and the record is saved successfully.  I return the JSON response as documentation suggests, but the KendoUI Grid stays in edit-mode.  If I click cancel, the underlying local data does not reflect the changes.  If I refresh, the changes are then shown correctly.  I need some help finding out why the update is not working.  Create and delete functions work fine.

```
<div style="width: 800px">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RoleGridModel>()
    .Name("grdRoles")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(r => r.Name).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(r => r.Description).Width(300);
        columns.Command(command => { 
            if (security.CanAdd || security.CanUpdate) command.Edit(); 
            if (security.CanDelete) command.Destroy();
            command.Custom("Manage Access").Click("manageAccess");
        })
        .Width(300);
    })
    .Groupable(grouping => grouping
        .Enabled(false))
    .Events(events => { if (security.CanAdd && !security.CanUpdate) events.DataBound("function() { this.table.find('.k-grid-edit').hide(); }"); })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(r => r.RoleId))
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Roles", new { area = "Setup" }))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Roles", new { area = "Setup" }))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Roles", new { area = "Setup" }))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Roles", new { area = "Setup" }))
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(r => r.Name).Ascending())
        .PageSize(10))
    .Filterable(filtering => filtering
        .Enabled(true))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable(paging => paging
        .Enabled(true)
        .Info(true)
        .PageSizes(false)
        .Refresh(true))
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling
        .Enabled(false)
        .Height(400)
        .Virtual(false))
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting
        .Enabled(true)
        .AllowUnsort(false)
        .SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
    .ToolBar(toolbar => { if (security.CanAdd) toolbar.Create(); })
)
```

```
        //
    // POST: /Setup/Roles/Edit

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, RoleGridModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Role r = Mapper.Map<RoleGridModel, Role>(model);
                r.AppContext = this.AppContext;
                r.SubscriberId = this.AppContext.SelectedSubscription.SubscriberId;
                r.SubscriptionId = this.AppContext.SelectedSubscription.SubscriptionId;
                r.ModifyDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                r.IsNew = false;
                r.IsMarkedForDelete = false;
                r.HasChanges = true;
                r.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(ex);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to update role. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
```

Comment: Per KendoUI documentation, you don't have to define an "id" field in the model as you specify the id in the datasource.Model(model => model.Id(r => r.RoleId)) binding.  See #5 http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-editing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there is a [breaking change](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string) in the new version of jQuery which affects the Kendo Q1 2013 version 2013.1.319.  An empty result is returned from the server on a successful update and destroy request.  This triggers the error as an empty result is not valid JSON.

There are 2 resolutions at this time:
1) Acquire the latest internal build of KendoUI as it has a fix.
2) Return a dummy object serialized as JSON.

```
return Json(ModelState.IsValid ? new object() : ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bill, it worked for me.

My update function was returning
**return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());**
and when i checked it was actually Void. Now i have returned an Object like you suggested and it works fine.

this works
**return Json(ModelState.IsValid ? new object() : ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());**